# SQLAlchemy Union Parenthesis Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

I need to generate a query similar to the following:

```
(select * from ... where .. and .. order by .. limit ..)
union all
(select * from ... where .. and .. order by .. limit ..)
order by ..
```

Using SQLAlchemy, I create two query objects as in:

```
q1 = Session.query(..).filter(..).filter(..).order_by(..).limit(..)
q2 = Session.query(..).filter(..).filter(..).order_by(..).limit(..)
q = q1.union_all(q2).order_by(..).all()
```

However it won't work because SQLAlchemy generates queries: q1 and q2 are not within parenthesis and it creates an error.

How can I get these statements inside parenthesis for q1 q2 union to result in above expressed query?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to create subqueries, then select from those subqueries:

```
from sqlalchemy import union_all

q1 = Session.query(..).filter(..).filter(..).order_by(..).limit(..).subquery()
q2 = Session.query(..).filter(..).filter(..).order_by(..).limit(..).subquery()
q = Session.query(..).select_entity_from(union_all(q1.select(), q2.select()).order_by(..).all()
```

The [`.subquery()` method](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery) returns an [Alias object](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Alias), which does not support `union_all` queries directly. So instead, we need to build a [`select_entity_from()` construct](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.select_entity_from), passing in the [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all()` *function*](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all) result instead, so you still get the results mapped to the correct objects.

Comment: Hi Martijn. What's the purpose of the unioning query's query() function here?

Comment: Your situation  *exactly* matches [this sqlalchemy list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/sqlalchemy/7qDKqM9t8eE).. it uses the same technique. `.subquery()` returns an alias object and that does not have a `union_all` method, so we have to use a `.select_from()` instead together with the `union_all` function.

Comment: It indeed does, and it indeed worked! Thank you. I've been searching non-stop for some time now on various locations and surprisingly did not find that thread. Silly me. Thanks again!

Comment: This did not work for me (I was getting extra rows) until I changed `select_from` to `select_entity_from`. Not sure why my case is different.

Comment: There was a change in behaviour in 0.9 (this answer predates 0.9) and `select_entity_from()` is now the correct method to use.