# Sort by a column in a union query in SqlAlchemy SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, union

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232596/how-to-sort-by-a-column-in-union-query-in-sqlalchemy), you can use string literals to do `order by` in `union`s.

For example, this works with Oracle:

```
querypart1 = select([t1.c.col1.label("a")]).order_by(t1.c.col1).limit(limit)
querypart2 = select([t2.c.col2.label("a")]).order_by(t2.c.col2).limit(limit)
query = querypart1.union_all(querypart2).order_by("a").limit(limit)
```

The order-by can take a string literal, which is the name of the column in the union result.

(There are gazillions of rows in partitioned tables and I'm trying to paginate the damn things)

When running against SQLite3, however, this generates an exception:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "ORDER": syntax error
```

How can you `order by` the results of a `union`?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/59465556/4399281

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queries that are part of a union query must not be sorted.

To be able to use limits inside a compound query, you must wrap the individual queries inside a separate subquery:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... LIMIT ...)
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... LIMIT ...)
```

```
q1 = select(...).limit(...).subquery()
q2 = select(...).limit(...).subquery()
query = q1.union_all(q2)...
```

Comment: This is an SQLite limitation?

Comment: @Will: The ordering on the component selects is useless anyway when you then sort the union, don't you think?

Comment: @MartijnPieters oops forgot the limit when I wrote up the question; updated.

Comment: @Will: right, in SQLite, only the [`select-core` grammar](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#select-core) can be used within a `UNION`; no `ORDER BY` allowed.

Comment: @Will: And as CL. shows, a *subquery* (`SELECT * FROM (SELECT ... ORDER BY ... LIMIT ...`) is allowed by the grammar. :-)

Comment: I am surprised that this works. A SQLAlchemy subquery does not have the method `union_all`/`union`. I had to do it like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673111/119937

Comment: @tsauerwein: the first `.subquery()` should probably be dropped, or use `select(q1).union_all(q2)`.