# SQLAlchemy : Column name on union_all

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is the mssql code snippet

```
(Select column_name_1 from table_name_1  with(nolock)  Where column_name_2='Y'
UNION ALL
Select column_name_1 from table_name_2  with(nolock)  Where column_name_2='Y'
)ae ON ae.column_name_1 = '1234'
```

I want to implement this in sqlalchemy and here is how i would approach it

```
q1 = session.query(table_name_1.column_name_1).filter(table_name_1.column_name_2=='Y')
q2 = session.query(table_name_2.column_name_1).filter(table_name_2.column_name_2=='Y')

q3 = q1.union_all(q2)
```

but

How would i get the column_name_1 from q3. How would i do this?

```
q3.column_name_1 == '1234'
```

went through the [sqlalchemy doc](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/)

Found similar questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21777730/sort-by-a-column-in-a-union-query-in-sqlalchemy-sqlite)

Comment: I was dealing with similar problem, but it was much more easier to do it using declarative mapping with [Abstract Concrete Classes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance.html#abstract-concrete-classes)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Code below should do it. Few notes:

- specify a `label` for a column, else `sqlalchemy` will create own unique name
- use [`sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.union_all), which will produce `Selectable` and not a `Query`

Code:

```
q1 = session.query(table_name_1.column_name_1.label("column_name_1")).filter(table_name_1.column_name_2=='Y')
q2 = session.query(table_name_2.column_name_1.label("column_name_1")).filter(table_name_2.column_name_2=='Y')

q3 = union_all(q1, q2)
q3 = select([q3.c.column_name_1]).where(q3.c.column_name_1 == '1234')
```

*Given your example, you could have actually added the filter directly to the original queries.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer van, But i am getting an AttributeError: 'Query' object has no attribute 'c'

Comment: Are you sure you are using `union_all` from the expression module and not still `q1.union_all(qs)`?