# How to filter only one subclass when loading inheritance in Sqlalchemy and apply order_by on union

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Looking at the example cited in the Sqlalchemy documentation [Loading Inheritance Hierarchies](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/inheritance_loading.html):

```py
engineer_employee = with_polymorphic(
    Employee, [Engineer], aliased=True)
manager_employee = with_polymorphic(
    Employee, [Manager], aliased=True)

q = s.query(engineer_employee, manager_employee).\
    join(
        manager_employee,
        and_(
            engineer_employee.id > manager_employee.id,
            engineer_employee.name == manager_employee.name
        )
)
q.all()
```

I'm wondering if there is a way, for example, to filter `Engineer` table only, keeping `Manager` data as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a problem like this one and the best solution I came with was using the `union` of the queries instead of `with_polymorphic`:

```py
q = Manager.query.union(Engineer.query.filter())  # Put your criteria inside filter. 
q.all()
```

In case you want to use `order_by` on `union`, just give it the necessary columns:

```py
q = Manager.query.union(Engineer.query.filter()).order_by(Manager.registered_on, Engineer.registered_on)
q.all()
```

Comment: but order_by doesn't work with union, do you have any suggestions for that ?