# SqlAlchemy core union_all not adding parentheses

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following sample code:

```
queries = []
q1 = select([columns]).where(table.c.id == #).limit(#)
queries.append(q1)
q2 = select([columns]).where(table.c.id == #).limit(#)
queries.append(q2)

final_query = union_all(*queries)
```

The generated SQL should be this:

```
(select columns from table where id = # limit #)
UNION ALL
(select columns from table where id = # limit #)
```

But, I'm getting

```
select columns from table where id = # limit #
UNION ALL
select columns from table where id = # limit #
```

I tried using `subquery`, as follows for my queries:

```
q1 = subquery(select([columns]).where(table.c.id == #).limit(#))
```

The generated query then looks like this:

```
SELECT UNION ALL SELECT UNION ALL
```

I also tried doing

```
q1 = select([columns]).where(table.c.id == #).limit(#)).subquery()
```

But, I get the error:

```
'Select' object has no attribute 'subquery'
```

Any help to get the desired output with my subqueries wrapped in parentheses?

Note: this is not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673060/sqlalchemy-union-parenthesis-issue), because I'm not using Session.

**EDIT**

Okay, this *works*, but I don't believe it is very efficient, and it's adding an extra `select * from (my sub query)`, but it works.

```
q1 = select('*').select_from((select(columns).where(table.c.id == #).limit(#)).alias('q1'))
```

So, if anyone has any ideas to optimize, or let me know if this is as good as it gets. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The author of SQLAlchemy seems to be aware of this and mentions a workaround for it on [the SQLAlchemy 1.1 changelog page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/migration_11.html#a-union-or-similar-of-selects-with-limit-offset-order-by-now-parenthesizes-the-embedded-selects). The general idea is to do `.alias().select()` on each select.

```
stmt1 = select([table1.c.x]).order_by(table1.c.y).limit(1).alias().select()
stmt2 = select([table2.c.x]).order_by(table2.c.y).limit(2).alias().select()

stmt = union(stmt1, stmt2)
```